# Import local package

Tags: go

My project structure looks like this:

```
--/project
----main.go
----/models
------user.go
```

In main.go I want to user user.go:

**user.go:**

```
package models

type User struct {
    Name string
}
```

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (...)

func main() {
    user := &User{Name: "Igor"}
}
```

How do I import user.go from main.go?

/project is under GOPATH, so I tried:

```
import "project/models"
```

but that does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your setup is right, you are using the package wrong.

change:

```
user := &User{Name: "Igor"}
```

to:

```
user := &models.User{Name: "Igor"}
```

or if you don't want to always say models.XXX, change your import to be.

```
import . "project/models"
```

I do find that doing this makes the code a bit harder to read, long term.
  It's obvious to the reader where "models.User" comes from, not so much with a plain "User" as normally that means it comes from this package.

Comment: Now, that was useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are building the project outside of a go workspace you can use [relative imports](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths):

```
import "./models"
```

However, using relative imports is not good idea. The preferred way is to import the full package path (and putting your project in a [proper go workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)):

```
import "github.com/igor/myproject/models"
```

Comment: Actually full path to project is $GOPATH/src/project. If I write import "project/models", shouldn't it work?

Comment: Anyway I get error saying: local import "./models" in non-local package

Comment: If it sits in $GOPATH/src/project, then you have a proper go workspace and you can't use local imports.

Comment: And instead you can just `import "projects/models"`

Comment: Still get ./main.go:11: imported and not used: "project/models"
./main.go:32: undefined: User

Comment: Yes, because in go imported type names should be qualified:

   `user := &models.User{Name: "Igor"}`